# Li click is not working with select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have a select menu built with [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin. I need to add a class to `<select>` when click menu options. Tested with alert it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/ysm4qhof/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.select2-results__option').on('click', function(){
   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
});
```

Tried with clicking ul but that also not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select2 .select2-results__options').on('click', function(){
       alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    });
    });
```

It should be working but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]this is working , first change selector to js-select2 because this class name you using for select  name and for select field use change function insted of click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.js-select2').on('change', function(){
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
});
```

Comment: Working fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use on select event of select 2 plugin.

```
$('.js-select2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
```

Check here for select2 documentation

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events